# Rmarkdown: Why graphics inside loop skips pages?

Tags: r, for-loop, ggplot2, markdown, r-markdown

I'm writing a report in Rmarkdown and I found some trouble plotting 
 ggplot2 graphics inside a for loop. The problem is that I'm getting a page skip between graphics in my PDF output.

My code works perfectly and I already tested a few alternatives:
I plotted two copies of some graphic outside any loop and the problem was solved. Also, printing some random message at the beggining and end of a iteration suggests that when the loop variable is incremented there is an automatic page break. Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance

EDIT: ADDING CODE

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggwordcloud)

for(i in 1:7){
  aux <- arrange(as.data.frame(extrai_palavras(dados[i, ], "count")), desc(Freq))
  med <- mean(aux$Freq)
  sd <- sd(aux$Freq)
  aux <- aux %>% filter(Freq - med > 2 * sd)
  ggwordcloud2(aux) %>% print()
}
```

I can't upload my data here, but it is a data frame with two colums, one the first is a word token and the second is the frequency of the word (Freq).

EDIT 2: REPRODUCIBLE EXAMPLE

Here is an reproducible example that makes absolutely no sense but produces my problem when a pdf is generated from it.

```
library(tidyverse)
treshold <- c(0, 10, 20, 30, 40)
for(i in 1:(length(treshold)-1)){
  plot <- mtcars%>%
    filter(mtcars$mpg > treshold[i] && mtcars$mpg < treshold[i+1]) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = disp, y = hp, fill = as.factor(cyl)))+
    xlab("") + 
    ylab("Total de ocorr?ncias") + 
    ggtitle("Palavras mais frequentes") +
    coord_flip() + 
    geom_point()
  print(plot)
}
```

Comment: It's easier to help if you can post a reproducible example

Comment: Hi Ariel your code works perfectly but without seeing your code or data, it's close to impossible for someone to help. Could you add sample data,code and expected/current output?

Comment: Note that we don't need your actual data, you can make up an example or use a built-in dataset.

Comment: Please check what the `aux` looks like by adding `print(aux)` at the end of your for loop. Maybe `aux` is empty or not the proper type for `ggwordcloud2` after a series of operation.

Comment: @Ariel: it's a good start but you need to post the `.Rmd` file as well to make it fully reproducible

Comment: @Tung Didn't get what is missing. It suffices to paste the code into a r chunk